# Search Engine displaying repeated search results

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a search engine project and have successfully done it on a separate test page. However, I'm facing issues when I try to integrate it into my original web-page design.

This is the test page I was referring to where the codes are working out fine, displaying results based on the "university" keyword.

[image: Search Engine]

And this is my original web-page design where I added the PHP codes for the search engine. The output is as shown. I am using the exact same codes, and connected to the same database. However, when I searched for the same keyword, which in this case is "university", I get different output from these two pages.

[image: Video Results]

This is my search engine script:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "null";
$database   = "seetoh88_mp16";

mysql_connect("$servername","$username",""); //Procedural style
mysql_select_db("$database");

$button = $_GET['submit'];
$search = $_GET['search']; 

if(!$button){
    echo "you didn't submit a keyword";
}
elseif(strlen($search)<=0){
    echo "Search term too short";
}
else{
    echo "You searched for <b>$search</b> <hr size='1'></br>";
}

$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

// An array for the `LIKE` conditions
$construct_list = [];

// Adding the conditions in the array
foreach($search_exploded as $search_each){
    $construct_list[] = "keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
}

// Joining them using OR
$construct = implode(" OR ", $construct_list);

// Supposing there are no keywords, the
// WHERE should not exist. So make a separate var for that - 
//$where_clause = "";
//if(trim($construct) != ""){
$where_clause = "WHERE $construct";
//}

// Perform your query
$query ="SELECT * FROM video INNER JOIN keyword
        on keyword.videoID = video.videoID
        $where_clause";

$runquery = mysql_query($query);

if ($runquery === false) {
    echo mysql_error();
}

$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($runquery);

if ($foundnum === false) {
    echo mysql_error();
}

if ($foundnum==0){
    echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for <b>$search</b>.";
}
else{
    echo "$foundnum results found !<p>";
    while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($runquery)){
        $videoID= $runrows ['videoID'];
        $thumbnail = $runrows ['thumbnail'];
        $title = $runrows ['title'];
        $description = $runrows ['description'];
        $keywords = $runrows ['keywords'];
        $embed_url = $runrows ['embed_URL'];

        echo "<a href='$embed_url'><b>$title</b></a><br>
        $description<br>
        <a href='$embed_url'>$embed_url</a><p>";
        echo "<a href='video-page.php'> <img src='$thumbnail' alt='' width='350px' height='200px'>";
    }
}
```

The Original web-page design

```
<div class="container bottom">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="portfolio-item classic">
            <div class="portfolio-item-thumbnail">
<?php 
$x = 1;
while($x<=3){
    echo "<a href='video-page.php'> <img src='$thumbnail' alt='' width='350px' height='200px'><hr>";
    $x++;
}
?>          </div><!-- portfolio-item-thumbnail -->
        </div><!-- col -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8"> 
        <div class="portfolio-item-description">
<?php
$y = 1;
while($y<=3){
    echo "<h4>$title</h4>";
    echo "<p>$description</p>";
    $y++;
}
?>      </div><!-- portfolio-item-description -->
    </div><!-- col -->
</div>
```

I would like to point out that i used a while loop to display the `$thumbnail` and `$description` retrieved from the database. Can anyone help me with regards to this matter? Many thanks!

Comment: Side note, don't put unfiltered variables directly into your sql statement. You are open to sql injection!

Comment: Also, when you do this: `Sorry, there are no matching result for <b>$search</b>` without `strip_tags` or using `htmlspecialchars`, someone could insert a javascript into the search field and your website would then run the script at that point, which could compromise your website.

Comment: Further to point 1) stop using `mysql_` functions and rather use `PDO` or `mysqli_` with prepared statements + variables that you can bind.